# How to change Ad network(in my Windows Phone Dev Center) associated pubCenter account number

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am submitting an app in Windows Phone Dev Center now and encounter a very hard-to-explain problem, so please be patient and allow me to explain it in details.

Step 1, I finished filling infomation in App info and then am trying to Add in-app advertising.

Setp 2. I clicked "Add in-app advertising"
In side this page, I have input a name for "Ad unit name" so I did it and clicked "Generate ad unit ID"

Step 3. I logged into my pubCenter and opened the "Overview" tab under "Steup" tab, I can see the App name under Applications section, but there is no Ad unit under the "Mobile application ad units" (oh yes, I'm submitting an WP8 app)

After hours and hours research and thinking, I found the problem which is in the Windows Phone Dev Center, here it is:

Open the "Account Summary" page, I saw the section "Ad network"
Inside this section, I saw this:

```
Ad network
pubCenter account number
X000YJBK
Edit payment and tax info for ad-funded apps through pubCenter.
```

The pubCenter account number X000YJBK is not my account number in pubCenter, instead it is a general account number for people who are learning how to publish an app.

But there is no way to change the associated pubCenter account number under Windows Phone Dev Center.

I do notice that the "Edit" is a link, but when I clicked it, it redirects me to the pubCenter page and leaves me with confusion and have no idea what to do in order to change the linked account number. (The statements followed "Edit" link doesn't say to change the linked account any way).

So my question is how to change the associated pubCenter account number for the Ad network in Windows Phone Dev Center.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this? I'm facing the same problem, not seeing in pubCenter the AdUnits generated in Windows Phone Dev Center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got help from Microsoft team and they are good people :)

Here is what the staff replied:

> Yes that App ID and Ad Unit ID deals with your account only. As for
>   creating these App ID's and Ad Unit Id's in PubCenter. Always do that.
>   Never from now on make the Ad units from Development center. This
>   option will be going away, and it is a good thing. Ad units from
>   Development center, is very unreliable to get Ad's. Also you do not
>   have the option to get correct reporting and you do not have the
>   option to edit the categories of your Ad Unit ID like in PubCenter.
>   PubCenter even though it seems to be just a bit out of what you are
>   wanting it to be, is all good to go for you. I am so glad that that it
>   is.

So let me make a summary:

1. It is okay that if you cannot change the associated Ad. Network account from Windows Phone Dev Center as this section (the Ad. Network inside your "Account Summary" page is going to be removed anyway)
2. The only thing matters is to always create your Application ID and Ad. Unit ID **INSIDE the pubCenter**
3. Do not be worried about it, you will receive money(according to their replies) as long as the Application ID and Ad Unit ID you use in your mobile app have linked to your bank account inside the pubCenter.

Okay, that's all for people who have the same problem and I am sure now you will feel released :)

Cheers